# GenSim : can I find a more "traditional" model?

Tags: python, model, nlp, dataset, gensim

I am experimenting with the beautiful GenSim package and downloaded the glove_42B_300D dataset.

I was a bit surprised to see that the result of

```
model.most_similar('apple')
```

gives

```
iphone
ipad
apples
blackberry
ipod
macbook
mac
android
google
microsoft
```

I mean, how about "apple", the fruit ?

For my purposes I need this meaning, not Apple the company.

Any solution you can think of ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's surprising, but you could try some sets of word-vectors other than `glove_42B_300D`.

Maybe the `glove.6B` set – which seem to be trained from different data, per the [GloVe page](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/)?

Or, the `GoogleNews` vectors that Google released alongside thei original `word2vec.c` code back in 2013. See: https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/

If all else fails, you can train your own vectors from training text that better reflects the meanings you want represented.